# Was MongoDB driver in-built module for NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm, dependencies

I am facing issues with a legacy NodeJS application. When I try to run it locally, it throws error `Error: Cannot find module 'mongodb'`. The error is thrown in a file, where I require `mongodb` module like this `const ObjectID = require("mongodb").ObjectID;`. I don't have `mongodb` mentioned in the dependencies in `package.json`. The confusing thing is that it used to work like this earlier, but now it suddenly started throwing this error. I tried different versions of NodeJS but keeps throwing the same error.

My question now is - Was there a particular version of NodeJS that didn't require us to install `mongodb` explicitly? And may be later versions dropped that support and required us to install it explicitly?

Comment: I've been using mongodb since `v12`  as a dependency, they don't natively support.

Comment: Thanks @YuvarajM I also ended up mentioning it as a dependency in package.json. What still confuses me is how it was running till now without this.